# Installing Apache Spark Packages to run Locally

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-avro

I am looking for a clear guide or steps to installing Spark packages (specifically spark-avro) to run locally and correctly using them with spark-submit command.

I've spent a lot of time reading many posts and guides, but still not able to get spark-submit to use the locally deployed spark-avro package. Hence, if someone has already accomplished this with spark-avro or another package, please share your wisdom :)

All the existing documentation I found is a bit unclear.

Clear steps and examples would be much appreciated! P.S. I know Python/PySpark/SQL, but not much Java (yet) ...

Michael

Comment: I think it would worth starting with your spark version.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In spark-submit command itself you can pass avro package details (make sure avro and spark version support)

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_<required_version>:<spark_version>
```

Example,

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.0
```

same way you can pass it along with spark-shell command as well to work on avro  files.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I am already aware of this approach. However, I need to deploy spark-avro locally and run spark-submit such that it uses this package stored in the local file system and not pulling it each time from the Internet - org.apache.spark. I believe I've explained that requirement in my post.

Comment: It wont download from internet each time. It will use downloaded jar in local file system during the second run.